# Tool to remove malware from laptop?

Tags: web-browser, antivirus, malware

I don't know how to remove such malware form PC. Because when I click anywhere in the web page, that click creates a new tab and show a new website, totally ads.

I have cleaned by PC with Windows Essential and as well as from CMD, but not solved.Even i have add different extensions to stop this but new tabs problem is not solved yet.

Comment: Why did you roll back my edit?

Comment: Once a computer gets infected, the ONLY safe way to clean it is to reformat and install the OS from scratch, from knwon-clean media. More on why is here: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit

Answer (score 1):

Try out [MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/)

> Malwarebytes Anti-Malware's industry-leading anti-malware and anti-spyware scanner detects and removes malware like worms, Trojans, rogues, spyware, bots, and more. Anti-rootkit technology drills down and removes deeply embedded rootkits, one of the most dangerous forms of malware.
>
> If you've got malware on your computer, Malwarebytes Anti-Malware will destroy it. Restoring your computer to its former glory.